# bootstrap modal window retain the old value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am having problem with bootstrap modal window my link for opening modal is like

```
<a href="#" 
  data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#postponed_modal"
  data-sch_date="{{sch_date}}" 
  data-flht_id="{{flht_id}}">Modal Window</a>
```

here sch_data and flht_id is dynamic which is set from angularjs .when i open modal for the first time it works fine all the values are correct but after changing the sch_data and flht_id value it shows change in link but in modal it shows same old value however i tried

```
$('#postponed_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#postponed_modal').removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

that doesn't work for me i am using bootstrap 3.3.4 and to get the value from link to modal

```
$('#postponed_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

      var schDate = $(e.relatedTarget).data('sch_date');
      var flhtId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('flht_id');
      $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="sch_date"]').val(schDate);
      $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="flht_id"]').val(flhtId);

   });
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you saying that changes are not reflecting back to your angular model?

Comment: no i am talking about modal window only

Comment: Without more info it looks like the link is providing the modal with data from the angularjs one-way bindings which are not updated between modal invocations?

Comment: actually the modal is not clearing the old value. Is there anyway to clear the old value of model?

Comment: If you mean "old value" as in the data supplied by the angular bindings, you'll need to update that data (sch_date, flht_id) yourself because they are one-way bindings.

Comment: what do mean by update the data yourself ? can you please provide some extra information as i am trying from 2 hours